# The device is not ready error when typing url on browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Stripe payment gateway for Ecommerce transaction. To communicate I have to use webhook url means I will provide a url so that they can commincate with us.
I created a controller and Action which is `[AllowAnonymus]`. When I run application locally and type controller and action on browser then it hit the action. But when I deployed on my test server and do the same it gives the following error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The device is not ready.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[IOException: The device is not ready.
]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +14840940
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1430
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +211
   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost) +210
   System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost) +87
   SchoolManagement.DTO.Entities.OrderItem.SavePartialCharge(String invoiceData) in c:\Atlassian\Bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\SMS-PPINBOX-JOB1\SchoolDTO\Entities\OrderItem.cs:185
   SchoolWeb.Controllers.StripeWebhookController.GetStripeResponse() in c:\Atlassian\Bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\SMS-PPINBOX-JOB1\SchoolWeb\Controllers\StripeWebhookController.cs:24
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +270
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +120
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +240
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

The following code written in Action:

```
public class StripeWebhookController : BaseController
    {
        //
        // GET: /StripeWebhook/

          [AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult GetStripeResponse()
        {
            Stream req = Request.InputStream;
            req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
            DTO.OrderItem.SavePartialCharge(json);
            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

Adding the method SavePartialCharge

```
public static String SavePartialCharge(string invoiceData)
        {
            try
            {

                string stripeEventType = BL.PaymentGateway.StripeReturn.GetStripeType(invoiceData);
                var obj = JObject.Parse(invoiceData);
                var dataObj = obj.SelectToken("data.object");
                var subscriptionID = dataObj.SelectToken("subscription").ToString();
                var customerID = dataObj.SelectToken("customer").ToString();
                var chargeID = dataObj.SelectToken("charge").ToString();
                var amount = Convert.ToDecimal(!dataObj.SelectToken("subtotal").ToString().IsNullOrEmpty() ?dataObj.SelectToken("subtotal").ToString() : "0");

                using (var db = new SchoolEntities())
                {
                    switch (stripeEventType)
                    {

                        case "invoice.payment_failed":
                            var resultorderFailed =
                                db.OrderItems.Where(oi => oi.MerchantServiceSubscriptionID == subscriptionID)
                                    .Select(oi => new {oi.ID, oi.Order.CreditCard4Digits})
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
                            if (resultorderFailed != null)
                                OrderItemInstallment.AddOrderItemInstallment(db, resultorderFailed.ID, amount,
                                    resultorderFailed.CreditCard4Digits, chargeID, false);
                            return "";
                        case "invoice.payment_succeeded":
                            var resultOrderSucceed =
                                db.OrderItems.Where(oi => oi.MerchantServiceSubscriptionID == subscriptionID)
                                    .Select(oi => new {oi.ID, oi.Order.CreditCard4Digits, oi.TotalInstallments})
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
                            if (resultOrderSucceed != null)
                            {
                                OrderItemInstallment.AddOrderItemInstallment(db, resultOrderSucceed.ID, amount,
                                    resultOrderSucceed.CreditCard4Digits, chargeID, true);
                                var count =
                                    db.OrderItemInstallments.Count(
                                        oii => oii.OrderItemID == resultOrderSucceed.ID && oii.Success);
                                if (count == resultOrderSucceed.TotalInstallments)
                                    BL.PaymentGateway.StripePaymentGateway.CancelSubscription(customerID,
                                        subscriptionID);
                            }
                            return "";
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\exception.txt", ex.Message);
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us the code with your StreamWriter, where the error occurs?

Comment: In your question please . Use  the edit button.

Comment: Ok, the error occurs at `SavePartialCharge(String invoiceData)`. Please show us this method.

Comment: I have added code. This method does not give error when I debug locally and works fine. Only it gives error on server. This method has try catch so this will not be the cause of error I guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your Stacktrace points to an error with a `StreamWriter`. According to your code, there is only one occurence of StreamWriter:

```
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\exception.txt", ex.Message);
 }
```

This means, an exception occurs and your catch block wants to log this exception to your local drive. This causes another exception, because there possibly is no drive D.
Logically, after you solved this exception, there will be another exception, which your catch block will then properly log.

Check your test machine, if a drive D is present (and it is no cd drive) and that your IIS user account has appropriate permissions.

On a sidenote: I wouldn't catch exception this way. This just pollutes a text file with error messages, without a stacktrace, timestamps etc. 
You could levarage one of the many Logging Frameworks already out there (NLOG for example) and make your live way easier.

Comment: You are right. This is a mistake from my side. The code in catch was just to check what all things stripe returns and saved in file . I hade to delete the code but I missed. Yes I will expect the exception here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The "Device is not ready" error seems to come out from Win32 as per http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,56cd161c65ab07fe,references. If it persists after ensuring the permissions are given and there is such drive it can be some hardware problem. In the case you can check at https://superuser.com/questions/364851/how-to-troubleshoot-the-device-is-not-ready-error-in-windows-xp Hope it helps!

PS. And yes it is not good way to keep logs (nlog, log4net, or manually into `App_data` folder").

Answer (score 0):

In my situtation, this issue occured when i'm passing the invalid invalid parameter name to the stored procedure from the .net code.

In my stored procedure, i declared the input parameter as 'caseId' but in the code i was calling the stored procedure with input parameter as 'case_Id' (with underscore).